# Air Pressure & Atmospheric Pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, atmospheric-science, gas

I know that when air is heated it expand, and thus it makes density decrease, pressure increase, and temperature increase. But, why hot air cools off when it expands and rise ?

Please answer with a long sentence.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! In general the rule is to have one question per post. Maybe a few  very related questions would also work. But a long list of questions is not the best thing to do. Perhaps you can ask what is that you are trying to understand, why do you care at so many (related) different questions?

Comment: I'm just curious and confused at the same time.

Comment: Ask them one by one not at once.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is in a closed container, the pressure of a heated sample of air is determined by the surrounding atmosphere.  As the density decreases, it rises, expands as the pressure drops, does work against the surrounding atmosphere, and loses internal energy.

Answer (score 0):

Look temperature of any gaseous system depends upon the kinetic energy of the molecules  and if the separation between two molecules is increased then the probability of collision decreases and thus their kinetic energy doesn't change to heat energy due to less collision. So when hot air expands the temperature decreases. So what is responsible for temperature of the gases is collision rate and their kinetic energies. Since there is no more collision the kinetic energy is then released finally.